# Using Matlab to solve $\sin(k+a)=x\cos(k)$ numerically for $a$

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, matlab

I want to solve a trigonometric equation numerically for $a$ via Matlab

$$\sin(k+a)=x\cos(k)$$

where $a$ is an argument of a complex number. Both $a$ and $k$ vary between $0\leq k\leq\pi$.

I want to have solution `sol[x,k]`, so that for each $x$ and $k$ I get (either zero, one, two or more) solutions $a$. Then to plot them, or visualize via a Table. This is done straightforwardly via Mathematica; however, I want to achieve it via Matlab, if easily possible. The code that I wrote upto now is

```
clear all
k=[0:0.1:pi]
x=[0:0.1:pi]
f=sin(k+a)-x*cos(k);
for i=1:3
    vpasolve(f,a,'random',true)
end
```

However, it doesn't get me any closer. Thanks.

Comment: What does MMA mean?

Comment: MMA = MatheMaticA

Comment: Yes Mathematica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try something like this:

```
clear all
syms a
for k=0:0.1:pi
  for x=0:0.1:pi
    f = sin(k+a) - x*cos(x);
    vpasolve(f,a)
  end
end
```

EDIT: The following code reflects most of the discussion in the comments.  It shows how to compute all solutions symbolically and stores them in a *cell array*:

```
syms a
k = sym(0:0.1:pi);
x = sym(0:0.1:pi);
T = cell(length(k),length(x));
for m=1:length(k)
  for n=1:length(x)
    if x(n) * cos(x) <= 1
      f = sin(k(m)+a) - x(n)*cos(x(n));
      sol = solve(f,a);
      T{m,n} = sol;
    end
  end
end
```

The entry of the array that are not assigned in the loop contain empty matrices, which are detected in further processing by calling `isempty`.

Comment: wow.. this is cool.. Thanks.. Actually there are many solutions, is there a way to also make a table of the solutions? so its easy to visualize them? for example in MMA I did `a = Table[sol[x, k], {x, 0.1, 3, 0.1}, {k, 0.1, 3, 0.1}];
MatrixForm[
 ArrayFlatten[{{{{"x\\k"}}, {Range[0.1, 3, 0.1]}}, {Partition[
     Range[0.1, 3, 0.1], 1], a}}]]
` This gave me a table of values to explicitly see the solutions, i.e., which ranges of x and k had one, two, three or no solutions. Secondly, a way could be to plot the solutions. How do i plot them? Thanks

Comment: Because Matlab keeps giving outputs (solutions) in the command window for quite some time. So I think a plot plus a table would be good option to visualize the solutions at some instances of x and k, to just get an overall picture.

Comment: It takes ages to complete the solution, if I give the range `k=0:0.1:pi` and `x=0:0.1:pi`.

Comment: Yes, it takes long when it fails to find a solution.  Of course, you can save the solutions in a two-dimensional array, instead of printing them to the console.

Comment: One way to speed up the computation would be to test whether $x\cdot \cos(x) > 1$ and skip the call to `vpasolve` if that's the case.  (See also the answer by @LutzL.)  If you don't need the precision of `vpasolve` you could use `fsolve`, which works with your machine's floating point numbers.  You'd have to provide an initial guess.

Comment: If you want to find all solutions, you should probably use `vpa(solve(f,a))`.  That is, first solve symbolically, and then convert to variable-precision (complex) numbers.  For the plot, I guess it depends on what you want to see.

Comment: How to get the output as a table(x,k)? I tried with this to only get `Var1   
    _________

    [1x1 sym]
    [1x1 sym]`

Comment: The command `T=table(x{:},k{:})` returns errors.

Comment: I've added some code to my answer that may address your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

You get the solutions 
$$
a=-k+\arcsin(x\cos(k))+2\pi n
$$
and 
$$
a=-k+\pi-\arcsin(x\cos(k))+2\pi n
$$
where $n$ has to be adjusted so that $0\le a<2\pi$. The additional restriction $a<\pi$ is then also a restriction on $k$ and $x$, that is, not all combinations might provide solutions.

Comment: @Lulzl exactly, there are regions in `x` and `k` with no solution, and regions with two solutions, and regions with single solutions.